# 80s/90s Sci Fi book about a pilot whose mind is linked to a spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I wished I remembered more. The front cover was a rather cool looking spaceship, in the novel it may have fired torpedoes. I was very young and don’t recall the story at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/book-about-a-man-who-can-interface-with-computers-travels-on-spaceship?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite a common trope, as are cool ships on covers... one question that might help however: when you say "links their mind", do you mean that they are literally controlling the ships functions as if they were part of their body (e.g. as in Anne McCaffrey's "brainship" series) or were they in psychic connection with an intelligent (perhaps even biological) ship (e.g. the Edenists' ships from Peter F Hamilton's "Confederation" universe)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot given such little information, but I'm going to suggest as a possibility either 'The Cyborg and the Sorcerers' or 'The Wizard and the War Machine', both by Lawrence Watt-Evans.  They were published in 1982 and 1987, respectively, and the latter is the sequel to the former.

According to Google, both have been reprinted with several different covers, so whether or not they have a 'cool looking ship' depends on the which cover you're looking at.

http://www.watt-evans.com/WarSurplus.shtml